# Li-poiy battery charge hold over time

Tags: batteries

I am developing a driver for a Li-Poly battery. This is the first time I am dealing with such battery. Does these types of battery always rise to the maximum voltage of 4.1 (based on the datasheet and measurement) even after several charge discharge? i.e. after 500 times.

I know by experience it cannot hold the same amount of charge over time, but can it always rise to the max voltage specified?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chargers usually do a constant current phase and then a constant voltage phase, and stop when the current to maintain the target voltage is small with respect to the initial charge rate.

The target voltage is the same per series cell, regardless of age or charge cycles.  So yes, for a battery that is still in fair operating condition, its voltage should be able to be taken to the same target voltage (usually 4.2V).